# Keeping associated class for a generic parameter

Tags: java, generics

I have some class with a generic parameter and for various reasons I need the concrete class associated with that parameter, so I'd like to take accept it as part of the constructor, e.g.:

```
public class Foo<T> {
    private final Class<T> clazz;
    public Foo(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }
}
```

I have some other class that I'd like to then construct this with that is also parameterized, e.g.:

```
public class MyObj<T> { /* stuff */ }
```

When I attempt to create a `Foo<T>` with a `MyObj`, I can't seem to work out the parameters to get things to compile. e.g. this fails:

```
Foo<MyObj<?>> foo = new Foo<MyObj<?>>(MyObj.class);
```

with a compile-time error like:

> The constructor `Foo<MyObj<?>>(Class<MyObj>)` is undefined

Similarly, when I provide concrete types for `MyObj` things still fail:

```
Foo<MyObj<String>> foo = new Foo<MyObj<String>>(MyObj.class);
```

with a compile-time error like:

> The constructor `Foo<MyObj<String>>(Class<MyObj>)` is undefined

I suspect the constructor argument for `Foo` is incorrect either in my definition of `Foo` or in my invocation of the constructor, but I'm not sure how to modify the type parameter.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Class` cannot represent parameterized types. The same `Class` object represents a `MyObj<String>` as a `MyObj<Integer>` (or rather there is no object of type `MyObj<String>`, there is only an object of type `MyObj`, generics are a compile time feature, they don't define an object at runtime).

If you simply had a non-generic

```
class MyObj {}
```

you could simply do

```
Foo<MyObj> foo = new Foo<>(MyObj.class);
```

But since your type is generic and you seem to want to maintain the type of its type argument, you'll need to go a step further. You'll need type tokens.

Guava provides a [`TypeToken`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html) class you can use. You'll have to change `Foo` to something like

```
class Foo<T> {
    final Type type;

    public Foo(Type type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

and then

```
Foo<MyObj<String>> foo = new Foo<MyObj<String>>(new TypeToken<MyObj<String>>() {}.getType());
```

Now if you print out the `type`, you'll see

```
com.example.MyObj<java.lang.String>
```

If you cast it to a `ParameterizedType`, you can then retrieve its parameterization.

Note, however, that you won't be able to get type safety here. You might accidentally write

```
Foo<MyObj<String>> foo = new Foo<MyObj<String>>(new TypeToken<MyObj<Integer>>() {}.getType());
```

and it will compile fine.

Comment: I ended up taking in a `TypeToken<T>` in the constructor instead of a `Type`, which should protect against the thing at the end of your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would just do:

```
  Foo<MyObj> foo = new Foo<MyObj>(MyObj.class);
```

If I actually knew what the higher level problem you were trying to solve was, I could give better advice. But all I have to work with is "Foo" and "MyObj"